# mysql_fetch_assoc crashing the php code

Tags: php, mysql

I need to change of not my PHP code and I ran into some problem (please notice that I usually code in Java and haven't develop in PHP for quite few years).

I have the following peace of code:

```
   $sql = "SELECT id_class FROM  events e join event_to_class ec on e.id = ec.id_event WHERE e.id = ".$r['id']."  and ec.id_evaluator = 8 and (".$stepNumbers.")";
   $mirekClassesForEvent = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql); 
   if (!$mirekClassesForEvent) {
      echo "Could not successfully run query from DB: " . mysql_error();
      exit;
   }               
   $mirekClasses = array();        
   if (mysql_num_rows($mirekClassesForEvent) > 0 ) {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mirekClassesForEvent) {
           array_push($mirekClasses, $row['id_class'];
      }
   }
```

the select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT id_class FROM events e join event_to_class ec on e.id = ec.id_event WHERE e.id = 1 and ec.id_evaluator = 8 and (e.id_step=4 OR e.id_step=5 OR e.id_step=6)
```

when I run it in the MySQL DB to runs fine and returns one row of data with

> id_class=27

.

However when I run the code above my php script crashes (it doesn't even show any error messages - even when I try to use `mysql_error()` function)

From my debuggin it looks like the problem is in the while statement, but I don't understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Next time it happens, look in your PHP error log. There should be a parse error, with the name of the file and the line number.

Comment: I would love to do that, however it isn't my code and it wasn't me who configured the environment. I tried to look for logs but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `)` at the end of the `while` line, and another on the `array_push` line. If you are seeing no error, you probably have error reporting off. Using an editor with syntax highlighting would help you find this kind of error, as they usually include highlighting of mismatched parentheses.

Note that you could simplify your query a little by using `IN`:

```
... and e.id_step IN (4,5,6)
```

Or `BETWEEN`:

```
... and e.id_step BETWEEN 4 AND 6
```

Comment: I must be blind! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error in your code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mirekClassesForEvent) {
       array_push($mirekClasses, $row['id_class'];
  }
```

You're missing the a closing bracket on your while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mirekClassesForEvent)) {
```

Editted to add:

And also one on the `array_push`, too - well spotted Kolink